# Не удаётся изменить размер View

Tags: java, android, view

Пробую реализовать жесты приближения и удаления по документации: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale

Создал свой элемент MyView и в зависимости от жеста пытаюсь увеличить/уменьшить его размеры. В логах вижу, что переменная `mScaleFactor` корректно меняет свои значения, но при этом сам элемент `MyView` не изменяется. Я подозреваю что проблема в методе `onDraw`, который должен перерисовать `MyView`, но не понимаю что происходит не так.

MyView.java

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    private final String TAG = "mytagfordebug";

    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }


    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }


    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener
            extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
            Log.d(TAG, "scale factor is:" + mScaleFactor);
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(MyView.this);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.example.e_vasiliev.zoominzoomout.MyView
        android:id="@+id/zoomView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#228"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вызывается ли ``onDraw()`` (в логах есть?) после того, как изменяется ``mScaleFactor``?

Comment: Да, метод корректно вызывается

Comment: В мануале пишут ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#restore() ), что restore() сбрасывает состояние к предыдущему save(). Попробуйте убрать или поменять местами.

Comment: Попробовал закомментировать restore() / менять местами - результат не изменился. Единственное что если resore() вызвать раньше save(), то получим ошибку и приложение упадёт (логично, ведь состояние восстанавливать неоткуда)

Comment: Еще вариант: перенесите ``super.onDraw(canvas);`` в самое начало метода.

Comment: К несчастью, это тоже не даёт ощутимых изменений

Comment: Почему-то мне кажеться, что перепутаны местами вызовы ` canvas.save();` и ' canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);` попробуйте их поменять местами и потом отдать в супер

Comment: Попробовал - результат не изменился

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. В данном случае меняется не сам размер элемента `View`, а его содержимое. Т.к. содержимого в нём нет, то увеличить собственно нечего. Для того чтобы видеть результат достаточно нарисовать в canvas любое изображение. Например:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.if_freebsd);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor);
    if (image == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Не удалось получить изображение. image = null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, p);
    }
    canvas.restore();
}
```